# Get total ans subtotal with MYSQL QUERY and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

In SQL I want to get total by id. Please suggest me for the query

**INPUT**

```
id | qty | price
1  | 3   | 200
1  | 4   | 225
1  | 5   | 250
2  | 7   | 300
2  | 8   | 300
3  | 3   | 500
3  | 5   | 500
3  | 6   | 500
4  | 3   | 700
4  | 2   | 745
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id | total
1  | 2750
2  | 4500
3  | 7000
4  | 3590
```

Comment: Please do not include image snapshots of your data, rather include actual text.

Answer (score 2):

This query sums the quantity times price for all records having the same `id`, for each `id` value in your table.

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(qty*price) AS total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
```